# Javascript scrolling select with favorite button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a favorite button that can be toggled on and off to each option in a standard select. I am using Bootstrap to style the select. Specifically, I need to create a UI element that allows me to scroll through the options and handle an event when I scroll to a new element. I want to extend this to include a toggle button to the left of each option, so I can mark an option as a "favorite."

**HTML**

```
<form>   
  <select id="scrollbox" multiple class="form-control target">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
      <option>Option 5</option>
  </select>  
</form>

<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  var e = document.getElementById("scrollbox");   
  document.getElementById("other").innerHTML = e.value;
});
```

How do I add a favorite button that can be toggled on and off to each option? I am open to alternative tools that emulate this behavior.

Comment: what do you mean by "favorite button" ?

Comment: So when you scroll to a certain point it selects one of them

Comment: By "favorite button," I mean a button I can add to each option that can be toggled on (favorite) and off (unfavorite). I should be able to handle an event when an option is favorited/unfavorited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like this? Have a checkbox on a div where the user clicks the option and class triggers your event? Inside of the event you can use the "this" keyword to reference the item being clicked.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UqYQR/4/)

HTML

```
 <form>   
      <div id="scrollbox" class="" sytle="display: block">
          <div id="1">Option 1 <input type='checkbox' class='handleFavorite'>Favorite</div>
          <div id="2">Option 2 <input type='checkbox' class='handleFavorite'>Favorite</div>
          <div id="3">Option 3 <input type='checkbox' class='handleFavorite'>Favorite</div>
          <div id="4">Option 4 <input type='checkbox' class='handleFavorite'>Favorite</div>
          <div id="5">Option 5 <input type='checkbox' class='handleFavorite'>Favorite</div>
      </div>  
    </form>
```

JS

```
$(".handleFavorite").click(function(){ alert('you clicked me')});
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. The toggle button should be associated with each option in the select box. Now if you could put the checkbox next to each option in the select... that would be more like something I was looking for.